# Is it possible to use Facebook's oAuth service without leaving users logged in to Facebook after they visit my site?

Tags: model-view-controller, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've got a test MVC site set up, and configured to log users in to it using Facebook's authentication systems. Once users log out of my system, *how do I ensure that the right thing happens wrt to the users being logged in to Facebook (ie, they revert to whatever state od logged in they were before visiting my site)?*

I'm relying on the FB api wrappers that are available to download through NuGet.

Several of the examples I see include a facebook logout method that can be called through the API, to let FB know that user(s) have logged out of my site, which, I assume, is supposed to "do the right thing". However, the method seems to have been removed from the library (and from the API?).

Is there some other method I should be calling, in order for the "right thing" to happen? Or, alternatively, some sort of workaround that people use?

It sees a bit disingenuous to ask people to access my site with their FB logins, only to have them surreptitiously remain logged in to FB after they've logged out of my site.

*Used workaround below (hand crafting a logout URL). Be careful of your url encoding*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Facebook's developer TOS](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) (item #6), you are required to log the user out of Facebook when the user logs out of your site (and used Facebook to login).

Consider the following use case:

A user accesses your site via a public computer (library) and opt to login (using facebook login) to access restricted features not available to users who are not logged in. The user conducts their business, then logs out. If you do not log them out of Facebook, their account is now available on the public computer, so if a new user uses the public computer after the initial user leaves, the new user could access the initial user's Facebook information.

Not sure about NuGet, but using [Facebooks PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), you simply need to call Facebook's [logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/) function which should generate a url with a next param, and access_token. So when the user clicks the logout link, they will be redirected to Facebook, logged out, then redirected back to your site to complete the logout process.

Example logout link:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3a%2f%2fextapi.yourhost.com%2flogout&rd=http%3a%2f%2fyourhost.com%2flogout&access_token=AAACRZBIZAGE18BAEyQ8AcmRKGGtmeYlw4MFYjuDHfTlZBSZA3pZAJ5xnKABELBmkOroaxlDsoPgFVHPvvkfZAFRQarCRL0Fhy7UrZCAZAfRFtvwBo4lY4s4X

Explained:

- next: This is the link the user will be redirected to after they are logged out of Facebook (this will be the domain you have registered with Facebook)
- rd: This is an arbitrary url param so when the user is redirected back to my site, I can redirect them back to another landing page (other than logout page).
- access_token: Is the access_token generated by Facebook when you logged the user in

Comment: I've tried redirecting to a logout link which follows that format, without success (the user is not logged out of facebook, and is not redirected back to my site afterwards)

Comment: Facebook won't log the user out if the access_token you pass to logout, doesn't match the access_token created when the user logged in. Are you using Facebook's PHP Api (`getLogoutUrl`) or creating the link on your own?

Comment: I'm creating the link on my own, using a stored copy of the access token

Comment: Can you post your 'next' url param value?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://localhost%3a3434&rd=http://localhost%3a3434

Comment: I've also tried using something like https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a3434&rd=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost2%3a3434

Comment: @blueberryfields: Ahhh, was going to say that you can't use localhost as the domain you registered with Facebook. Facebook needs a host that is preset via the Facebook Developer page so when it gets your request, it recognizes the host, and handles the redirect back to your site correctly. Can you update your OP with what you did to fix your problem (future reference for others)? Thanks.

Comment: localhost works just fine - my issue ended up to be one of properly encoding the slashes and dashes in the url I used for next

Comment: @blueberryfields: It sounds like you may be using the deprecated oauth API. The new (oauth2) API forces you to register a hostname with Facebook, so requests being made on your behalf can also be authenticated. Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ for more info.